# How can I change the first element in a list from string to date format?

Tags: python, string, list, datetime

I have the following text file that has these lists :

```
['2009-08-31 23:58:06 ', '1']
['2009-08-31 23:58:06 ', '1']
['2009-08-31 23:58:06 ', '0']
['2009-08-31 23:58:06 ', '1']
['2009-08-31 23:58:06 ', '1']
['2009-08-31 23:58:06 ', '1']
['2009-08-31 23:58:06 ', '1']
['2009-08-31 23:58:06 ', '1']
['2009-08-31 23:58:06 ', '1']
['2009-08-31 23:58:06 ', '1']
['2009-08-31 23:58:06 ', '1']
['2009-08-31 23:58:07 ', '1']
['2009-08-31 23:58:07 ', '1']
['2009-08-31 23:58:07 ', '1']
```

The second element is an integer, however, the first element is a string. I need the first element of each lis to be a date instead of string?

I tried this code:

```
 word[0]=datetime.strptime(word[0],'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

but I get this error:

```
ValueError: time data '2009-04-02 22:50:06 ' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'
```

the current code I have that cleans the data is the following:

```
with open('newdata.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
       tweet=re.sub(r'T\t',"",line)
       t=re.sub(r'W\t',"\/\/",tweet)
       data=t.split("\/\/")
       sentiment_value= s.sentiment(data[1])
       data.append(sentiment_value)

       words = [w.replace('pos', '1') for w in data]
       word=[w.replace('neg','0')for w in words]
       del word[1]
       print(word)
```

Comment: change format from %Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S' to %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: `datetime.strptime('2009-08-31 23:58:09 '.strip(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: downvoting because of a miscommunication is not very nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
datetime.strptime(word[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S ')
```

will work. Note the `'-'` and the trailing space. Depending on your use case and whether you have more and differently dirty data, you might be better off stripping the input or using some more robust utility like [dateparser](http://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: i got this error: ValueError: unconverted data remains:

Comment: I am very sorry. It seems that I missed the space you have added at the end. I have removed my answer and accepted yours as soon as I noticed that. Please accept my sincere apology =>

Answer (score 0):

Simply write:

```
from datetime import datetime
word=['2009-08-31 23:58:09 ', 1]
value = datetime.strptime(word[0].strip(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(value)
```

Note: If you don't strip white space of both sides then you will get `unconverted data remains` error.

Comment: I couldn't move it because I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
word = ['2009-08-31 23:58:09 ', 1]
```

Change '%Y/%m%d %H:%M:%S' to '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

```
word[0]=datetime.datetime.strptime(word[0],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: i got this error.     AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: If use from datetime import datetime,  code is datetime.strptime(word[0],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
otherwise,  import datetime, code is datetime.datetime.strptime(word[0],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Comment: AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'